# Calabash-android background and open an app 0.5.14?

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

Is this possible with calabash-android? I see this http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/calabash/Calabash/LifeCycle.html#send_current_app_to_background-instance_method

But is that does not seem to be in my version of calabash-android 0.5.14

Answer (score 0):

That documentation is for Calabash 2.0.

The docs for Calabash Android 0.x are here: http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/android/

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So 2 questions. 1. Is backgrounding an app and then resuming it possible currently? 2. When is 2.0???? Exciting!

Comment: You can look at the implementation in Calabash 2.0.  The release date is TBD.  Calabash 2.0 is pre release.